# OCaml constructor unpacking

Tags: syntax, ocaml

Is it possible to unpack a type by binding its data to a single value instead of a tuple?

```
# type foo = Foo of int * string;;
type foo = Foo of int * string
# Foo (3; "bar");;
  Foo (3; "bar");;
Error: The constructor Foo expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
# Foo (3, "bar");;
- : foo = Foo (3, "bar")

# (* Can this possibly work? *)
# let Foo data = Foo (3, "bar");;
  let Foo data = Foo (3, "bar");;
Error: The constructor Foo expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)

# (* Here is the version that I know works: *)
# let Foo (d1, d2) = Foo (3, "bar");;
val d1 : int = 3
val d2 : string = "bar"
```

Is this syntactically possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variant type constructor with just one tuple value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774671/using-a-variant-type-constructor-with-just-one-tuple-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a tricky part of OCaml syntax.  If you define your type as you show, its constructor `Foo` expects two values in parentheses.  And it always has to be two values, it's not a single value that's a tuple.

If you're willing to use a different type, you can do something more like what you want:

```
# type bar = Bar of (int * string);;
type bar = Bar of (int * string)
# let Bar data = Bar (3, "foo");;
val data : int * string = (3, "foo")
# let Bar (d1, d2) = Bar (3, "foo");;
val d1 : int = 3
val d2 : string = "foo"
```

When declared this way, the constructor `Bar` expects *one* value that's a tuple.  This can be more flexible, but it also takes a little more memory to represent it, and a little longer to access the parts.