# What's the difference between these two type definitions in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

`type t1 = A of int * string` and `type t2 = A of (int * string)`, are they different or the same?

In this [functional programming tutorial](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/Functional/functional-lecture02.pdf), slide 6, it says

> In OCaml, variants take multiple arguments rather than taking tuples
>   as arguments: A of int * string is diﬀerent than A of (int * string).
>   But it’s not important unless you get bitten by it.

But I don't see any difference other than a pair of parenthesis.

Comment: These are two different types. This has been asked and answered many times on SO. Here are examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818866/int-int-vs-int-int-in-ocaml-sum-type/14819463#14819463 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306733/ocaml-constructor-unpacking/10306865#10306865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
type t1 = A of int*int
type t2 = B of (int*int)
let x = (1,2) in A x (* does not work *)
let x = (1,2) in B x (* works *)
```

That is, `B` is a constructor expecting 1 argument (namely a tuple containing two integers), while `A` is a constructor accepting 2 arguments (supplied as a parenthesized, comma-separated thing).